# Creating the custom marker using Google Static Map Api and define the rotation and color of marker Dynamically

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I am creating a static Image using google-static-map API.I want to create my custom Icon on Google Static Map.I want to rotate the Icon dynamically.
**Without Using JS.**

Url:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.52333,77.25357&zoom=5&size=640x540&path=color:blue|weight:3|28.5686,77.1122|28.51408,77.35803|25.94966,76.87709|22.52333,77.25357&markers=anchor:center|icon:|size:tiny|22.52333,77.25357&markers=color:red%7Clabel:D%7C12.995,80.1756&markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C28.5686,77.1122&key=AIzaSyAw2hC8vM8_q4y0f_Ak8YNXRQYQmjaZwK4

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward question which you can ask google also. If you are finding any difficulty implementing it, pls post it here. By the way, you can follow this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Comment: Hi, I am using the google-static-map api for generating the static image an area with icons for particular location.I want to rotate this icon dynamically. This is the issue. 
I didnt find any way to implement it,Only using other images as marker are there but how to rotate that markerthis Part i am not able to get?
Thanks